# How to check if a fixed string contain any additional character?

Tags: php, strpos

This code check if "have" is present inside the string, assuming the string **always** begin with "I have found" what i need is a function that check if the string contain "I have found" plus something else. Example: I have found 500. where 500 can be anything, and unknow.

```
 $a = 'I have found';
 if (strpos($a, 'have') !== false) {
 echo 'true';
 }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `strpos` accomplish that? https://3v4l.org/MWe3R

Comment: I need to know two things: if the string is I have found, and if there is any additional character or number more than "i have found".

Comment: You mean you need to know the trailing integer value, or if there are any other characters? https://3v4l.org/rMV9U for any other characters. Use a regex for integer check, add optional whitespace and integer `(\h+\d+)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what has been found:

```
function get_found($str){
    if(strpos($str, "I have found")===false)
        return "nothing";
    $found = trim(substr($str, strlen("I have found")));
    if($found == "")
        return "nothing";
    return $found;
}

echo get_found("I have found a friend"); //outputs "a friend"
echo get_found("I have found"); //outputs "nothing"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match()`, like in this code:

```
$a = 'I have found'; //fixed string
$str = 'I have found 500';
if (preg_match('/^'.$a.'(.+?)$/', $str, $m)){
 echo 'The string contains additional: '.$m[1];
}
else echo 'String fixed';
```